# Android Rotate Animation left to right 3d

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-imageview

In my android aplication, I need to rotate an imageview from left to right like in 3d, I did rotation like clockwise from left right, But I didnt got a proper solution for left to right can anybody help me, I am giving my rotation code it is working but it is rotating like clockwise same as in 2d.

```
RotateAnimation r;
        r = new RotateAnimation(ROTATE_FROM, ROTATE_TO, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        r.setDuration((long) 4*1500);
        r.setRepeatCount(0);
        favicon.startAnimation(r);
```

Comment: You can find 3D flip animation example at : http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

Comment: Check Raghav Chopra's the 3D flip library hear : https://code.google.com/p/android-3d-flip-view-transition/